# Timing in Ticket System

Tags: c#

I have nearly finished a project I've been working on for over three months. This is my first program I've ever made, so it may not be the cleanest code but for the most part works. The only issue I'm having now is getting the times to line up between specific times (In this instance 8am and 3pm). I am getting times outside of these times instead of inside. My current code is

```
if (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timetoadd).Hour < 8)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Too early_Button Pressed");
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var today8am = now.AddDays(0).Date.AddHours(8);
    double totalHours = (today8am - now).TotalHours;
    MessageBox.Show("totalHours=" + totalHours);

    double hourstoadd = 0;// = timetoadd / 60;
    MessageBox.Show("TTA = " + timetoadd.ToString());
    do
    {
        hourstoadd++;
        if (DateTime.Now.AddHours(hourstoadd).Hour == 15)
        {
            hourstoadd = hourstoadd + 17;
        }
        timetoadd = timetoadd - 60;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(hourstoadd.ToString());
    }
    while (timetoadd >= 60);

    MessageBox.Show("TTA2 = " + timetoadd.ToString());
    do
    {

        hourstoadd = hourstoadd - 8;
        daystoadd++;
        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday")
        {
            daystoadd = daystoadd + 2;
        }
        else if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
        {
            daystoadd = daystoadd + 1;
        }
    }
    while (hourstoadd > 8);
    if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(daystoadd).AddHours(hourstoadd).Date.AddHours(hourstoadd + now.Hour).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday")
    {
        daystoadd = daystoadd + 2;
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(daystoadd).AddHours(hourstoadd).Date.AddHours(hourstoadd + now.Hour).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
    {
        daystoadd = daystoadd + 1;
    }
    EstimatedCompleteDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(daystoadd).AddHours(hourstoadd).Date.AddHours(hourstoadd + now.Hour).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("ETA = " + EstimatedCompleteDate);

}
else if (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timetoadd).Hour > 15)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Too Late_Button Pressed");
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var tomorrow8am = now.AddDays(1).Date.AddHours(8);
    double totalHours = (tomorrow8am - now).TotalHours;
    MessageBox.Show("totalHours=" + totalHours);

    double hourstoadd = 0;// = timetoadd / 60;
    MessageBox.Show("TTA = " + timetoadd.ToString());
    do
    {
        hourstoadd++;
        if (DateTime.Now.AddHours(hourstoadd).Hour == 15)
        {
            hourstoadd = hourstoadd + 17;
        }
        timetoadd = timetoadd - 60;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(hourstoadd.ToString());
    }
    while (timetoadd >= 60);

    MessageBox.Show("TTA2 = " + timetoadd.ToString());
    do
    {

        hourstoadd = hourstoadd - 8;
        daystoadd++;
        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday")
        {
            daystoadd = daystoadd + 2;
        }
        else if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
        {
            daystoadd = daystoadd + 1;
        }
    }
    while (hourstoadd > 8);
    if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(daystoadd).AddHours(hourstoadd).Date.AddHours(hourstoadd + now.Hour).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday")
    {
        daystoadd = daystoadd + 2;
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(daystoadd).AddHours(hourstoadd).Date.AddHours(hourstoadd + now.Hour).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
    {
        daystoadd = daystoadd + 1;
    }
    EstimatedCompleteDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(daystoadd).AddHours(hourstoadd).Date.AddHours(hourstoadd + now.Hour).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("ETA = " + EstimatedCompleteDate);
}
else if (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timetoadd).Hour <= 15 && DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timetoadd).Hour >= 8)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Regular hours");
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var tomorrow8am = now.AddDays(1).Date.AddHours(8);
    double totalHours = 0;
    MessageBox.Show("totalHours=" + totalHours);

    double hourstoadd = 0 + now.Minute;// = timetoadd / 60;
    MessageBox.Show("TTA = " + timetoadd.ToString());
    do
    {
        hourstoadd++;
        if (DateTime.Now.AddHours(hourstoadd).Hour == 15)
        {
            hourstoadd = hourstoadd + 17;
        }
        timetoadd = timetoadd - 60;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(hourstoadd.ToString());
    }
    while (timetoadd >= 60);

    MessageBox.Show("TTA2 = " + timetoadd.ToString());
    do
    {

        hourstoadd = hourstoadd  - 8;
        daystoadd++;
        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday")
        {
            daystoadd = daystoadd + 2;
        }
        else if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
        {
            daystoadd = daystoadd + 1;
        }
    }
    while (hourstoadd > 8);
    if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(daystoadd).AddHours(hourstoadd).Date.AddHours(hourstoadd + now.Hour).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday")
    {
        daystoadd = daystoadd + 2;
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(daystoadd).AddHours(hourstoadd).Date.AddHours(hourstoadd + now.Hour).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
    {
        daystoadd = daystoadd + 1;
    }
    EstimatedCompleteDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(daystoadd).AddHours(hourstoadd).Date.AddHours(hourstoadd + now.Hour).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("ETA = " + EstimatedCompleteDate);
}
```

`timetoadd` = `sum + current_ticket_time in minutes`.
`sum` = `all previous ticket times`.
I am using Messagebox's to provide me a form of immediate feedback.

Comment: If I had to venture a guess var today8am = now.AddDays(0).Date.AddHours(8); is the culprit.  You should rethink this.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to DateTime.Today.AddDays(0).AddHours(8).date and still no difference, I'm not sure the best way to force it to go to tomorrow at 8am.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step through it and see if everything is as expected at each step in execution?

Comment: Alright I added some more messageboxes, and realized that even though I am telling it to add 8 hours, it is showing up as 6/22/2016 12:00am. Also I am unsure how to do that with Visual Studio except the debugger that allows me to actually use the program.

Comment: Okay so I now have it so all the today8am/tomorrow8am are correct along with figured out breakpoints(Thank you so much for that!), but am still not getting the desired hours. This is my first program so I am still at a complete loss at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The other night I was able to get a script that works for exactly what's needed.

```
var soonh = 0;
                            var now = DateTime.Now;
                            var soonm = 0;
                            double minutestoadd = timetoadd;
                            int hourstoadd = 0;
                            if (minutestoadd >= 60)
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    minutestoadd = minutestoadd - 60;
                                    hourstoadd++;
                                }
                                while (minutestoadd > 60);
                            }
                            soonh = 6 - (Convert.ToInt32(now.Hour));
                            soonm = 60 - ((Convert.ToInt32(now.Minute)));
                            if (soonm < 0)
                            {
                                var temp = soonm;
                                soonm = 0;
                                soonh = soonh - 1;
                                soonm = 60 + temp;
                                Console.WriteLine("Sample");
                            }
                            double totalmin = soonm + now.Minute + minutestoadd;
                            if (totalmin >= 60)
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    if (totalmin >= 60)
                                    {
                                        totalmin = totalmin - 60;
                                        hourstoadd = hourstoadd + 1;
                                    }
                                }
                                while (totalmin >= 60);
                                if (soonh < 0)
                                {
                                    soonh = 0;
                                }
                                int totalhour = soonh + now.Hour + hourstoadd;
                                int totalday = 0;
                                bool sample = false;
                                do
                                {
                                    if (totalhour >= 8)
                                    {
                                        totalhour = totalhour - 7;
                                        totalday = totalday + 1;
                                        sample = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                while (totalhour >= 8);
                                if (sample == true)
                                {
                                    totalday = totalday - 1;
                                }
                                totalhour = totalhour + 7;
                                if (totalhour + DateTime.Today.Hour >= 15)
                                {
                                    totalhour = totalhour - 7;
                                }
                                if (DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(totalday) == DateTime.Today)
                                {
                                    totalday++;
                                }
                                EstimatedCompleteDate = (DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(totalday).AddHours(totalhour).AddMinutes(totalmin).ToString());
                            }
```